# Two cars tied with a spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, energy-conservation, spring

> A spring of spring constant $k$ is tied with two cars of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ with a rope. As a result, the spring is compressed by $x$ meters. Initially, assume that they are at rest. Suddenly, the rope is cut. Find the velocities of the two cars with which they would depart.
> [image: 1]

Originally, my approach of dealing with it was energy and momentum conservation, so I thought of using
$$\frac{1}{2}kx^2=\frac{1}{2}m_1{v_{1}}^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2{v_{2}}^2 \\ m_1v_1+m_2v_2=0$$
but it turned out my approach was wrong.

The book had this equation
$$\frac{1}{2}m_1{v_{1}}^2=\frac{1}{2}\frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}kx^2$$
and they mentioned that the were considering distances with respect to center of mass. They didn't explain how they jumped into the equation and I also didn't understand how they deduced the equation and what they mean by *considering distances with respect to center of mass* as I don't have much experience regarding the center of mass. Please help.

Comment: If you simply use your second, correct equation to eliminate v_2 from your first, correct equation, you get the book's single correct equation...

Comment: you got two equations, for the two unknown v1 and v2, every think is o.k

Answer (score 0):

With centre of mass, this question becomes easier. The mentioned answer might be derived using this concept. Actually, you must need to know kinetic energy wrt centre of mass frame:
$$K = \sum_i^n \frac{1}{2} m_i {v^\prime_i}^2 + \frac{1}{2}M_{\text{total}}V_{cm}^2$$

I am leaving derivation and more information [here](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Variational_Principles_in_Classical_Mechanics_(Cline)/02%3A_Review_of_Newtonian_Mechanics/2.10%3A_Work_and_Kinetic_Energy_for_a_Many-Body_System)

Here $v_i^\prime$ is velocity of $i$'th particle wrt centre of mass frame.  $$v^\prime_i=v_i-V_{cm}$$

For two body situation our main equation becomes $$K=\frac{1}{2} \frac{m_1m_2}{m_1+m_2}v_{rel}^2+\frac{1}{2}MV_{cm}^2$$
where $v_{rel}=|v_2-v_1|$

Now coming to our question, here no external force is acting, so centre of mass remains at **rest**. Only force acting is spring force, which is counted as internal. So $V_{cm}=0$, which reduces to: $$m_1v_1+m_2v_2=0\,\,\, (1)$$

Now our equation of kinetic energy becomes $$ K=\frac{1}{2} \frac{m_1m_2}{m_1+m_2}v_{rel}^2\,\,\,(2)$$
And now $\frac{1}{2}kx^2=K$

Using equations (1), (2) we can find $v_1,v_2$.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Since the center of mas does not move, measuring the velocities relative to the center of mass does not change the velocities. Solve your momentum equation equation for $v_2$. Put that in the energy equation and solve for (1/2)$m_1({v_1}^2)$. You get the given result.